# How to import videojs-offset

Tags: angular, typescript, video.js

I have the following component

```
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  AfterViewInit,
  ViewChild,
  Input,
  EventEmitter,
  Output
} from '@angular/core';
import * as videojs from 'video.js';
import * as hls from 'videojs-contrib-hls';

require('videojs-offset');

export type VideoPlayerEvent = 'play' | 'pause' | 'ended';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-player',
  templateUrl: './video-player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-player.component.css']
})
export class VideoPlayerComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('videoPlayer', { static: false })
  videoPlayer: ElementRef;

  @Input()
  videoUrl: string;

  @Input()
  videoType: string;
  /** Subject that emits when the component has been destroyed. */

  @Input()
  clipIn: string;

  @Input()
  clipOut: string;

  @Output()
  onPlayerEvent = new EventEmitter<VideoPlayerEvent>();
  videoJsPlayer: videojs.Player;
  constructor() { }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.videoUrl) {
      const self = this;
      this.videoJsPlayer = videojs(this.videoPlayer.nativeElement, {}, function () {
        this.on('play', () => self.onPlayerEvent.emit('play'));

        this.on('pause', () => self.onPlayerEvent.emit('pause'));

        this.on('ended', () => self.onPlayerEvent.emit('ended'));
        return hls;
      });
      if(this.clipIn && this.clipOut) {
        this.videoJsPlayer.offset({
          start: this.clipIn,
          end: this.clipOut,
          restart_beginning: false
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am attempting to use the videojs-offset library to stream a section of a HLS stream dictated by **clipIn** and **clipOut**

I am receiving the following error on compilation

```
ERROR in ../../libs/reusable-ui/video-player/src/lib/components/video-player.component.ts:55:28 - error TS2339: Property 'offset' does not exist on type 'Player'.
```

I assume this is due to me importing the library incorrectly, which is strange as the docs state to import it as such

```
require('videojs-offset');
```

Would anyone be able to tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a closed issue on Github regarding this. The author suggests the following:

Add it in your `angular.json`:

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/video.js/dist/video.js",
   "node_modules/videojs-offset/dist/videojs-offset.js"
]
```

Remove `require('videojs-offset');` and use globally as `window['videojs']`.

Read more here https://github.com/cladera/videojs-offset/issues/38

Comment: Would you be able to explain how I am supposed to implement the player in my code? I am still seeing an error that 
'offset does not exist on player'